Unable to include xsltexports.h
While compiling a pro*c code which includes xslt.h file i am getting
Error at line 14, column 10 in file /usr/include/libxslt/xslt.h #include "xsltexports.h" .........1 PCC-S-02015, unable to open include file Syntax error at line 62, column 12, file /usr/include/libxslt/xslt.h: Error at line 62, column 12 in file /usr/include/libxslt/xslt.h
Both xslt.h and xsltexports.h are present under /usr/include/libxslt.
Why compiler is not able to include this header file ?

"Syntax error at line 62, column 12"
